# crontab call shell script got import error

Tags: python, shell, cron

the crontab script is :`0 6 * * * cd /path/to/shell/script && sh script.sh`

the script.sh call a python file like this:

```
/opt/tiger/spark_deploy/spark-test/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--num-executors 200 \
--driver-memory 8g \
--executor-memory 10g \
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.cluster.name=topi \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=200 \
--conf spark.local.dir=/data01/home/zhaimo/tmp \
--queue root.topi_ad_hadoop \
client.py --date ${yesterday} --pay_num 100 | tee r.log${yesterday}
```

in the client.py, I import several models including my own packages like this `from ad_meteor_api_pyrpc.thrift_gen.ad.meteor.meteor_rpc.ttypes import *`

when I start up the crontab, it comes up

```
ImportError:can't import * from ad_meteor_api_pyrpc.thrift_gen.ad.meteor.meteor_rpc.ttypes
```

but when I run script.sh by myself, all things go on right.
How to solve this problem, please?

Comment: script in crontab mostly runs as differen user, with different privilages, in different folder, etc. - all for security reason. You may have to add folder with your module to `sys.path` so pythoun could find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try sourcing your user's profile file in your crontab command, before the script execution, eg :

```
0 6 * * * . ~/.bash_profile ; cd /path/to/shell/script && sh script.sh
```